# Why is choice returning errorlevels oddly?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
choice /c 123456789 >NUL
if errorlevel = 9 if %ui9%==9 set "ui9=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 8 if %ui8%==8 set "ui8=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 7 if %ui7%==7 set "ui7=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 6 if %ui6%==6 set "ui6=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 5 if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 4 if %ui4%==4 set "ui4=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 3 if %ui3%==3 set "ui3=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 2 if %ui2%==2 set "ui2=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
if errorlevel = 1 if %ui1%==1 set "ui1=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot
cls
echo That spot's already taken
ping localhost -n 3 >NUL
goto medmoduleuser
```

I'm making a tic-tac-toe bot. When entering a digit such as 9, then entering it again in the next turn, it will trigger the `if errorlevel = 8 if %ui8%==8 set "ui8=X" & set /a moves = %moves% + 1 & goto :medmodulebot` instead of just going through the code until it hits the bottom... It seems that `choice` is returning errorlevels oddly? What do I do to prevent this?

Comment: `if errorlevel = 9` You probably want `if errorlevel 9` instead.

Comment: Like @dxiv says, your way of comparison is not correct. Try `%errorlevel%  equ 9` and `%errorlevel%==9` as well as dxiv's solution.

Comment: Note `if errorlevel 9` is the robust method and the documented way. Other ways **depend** on user/other batch files not setting `%errorlevel%`. If they do it stops being a special variable and won't change its value. Program as if other programs and the user will try to trash your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments, errorlevel testing could be avoided completely. By converting the choice value into the literal value with a for / F loop metavariable

```bat
@echo off & Setlocal ENABLEdelayedexpansion
Rem // script body
For /F "Delims=" %%C in ('Choice /N /C:123456789') do (
    if !ui%%C!==%%C (
        set "ui%%C=X"
        set /a moves+=1
        goto :medmodulebot
    )
)
cls
echo That spot's already taken
ping localhost -n 3 >NUL
goto medmoduleuser
```